# how to know sharepoint server is foundation or standard using csom?

Tags: csom

I want to know how to find out the SharePoint server is enterprise, foundation or standard using c#.

Answer (score 1):

If the account running the code has the appropriate permission on the site you can iterate the Features and look for SharePoint Server Features.